# Keras: Multiply with a (constant) numpy-matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, neural-network, keras

Is it somehow possible in Keras (neural network library) to do a multiplication with a fixed / given `numpy` array?

I like to multiply the output of a 2D-convolution with a matrix. I tried to use `Backend.dot`, but it does not seem to work (i always get some errors like `numpy.ndarray` object has no attribute `get_shape`).

Thank you

-edit-

I found a solution (already yesterday, anyway: thanks for the comments). I liked to convert a 2D-spectrum to a 2D-mel-spectrum inside the network (not trainable). The 2D-spectrogram may be seen as a large matrix and then the mel-spectrogram may be calculated via a matrix multiplication.

Long story short: I used a TimeDistributed Dense-Layer without a bias. I just load the weights (=the constant matrix) and thats it:

```
# Change time / frequency axis (required for TimeDistributed)
nw = input_layer
nw = Permute((2, 1))(nw)

# Create a layer that computes the Mel spectrogram
mel_basis = librosa.filters.mel(22050, N_FFT)[:, :spectrogram_freqs] # The spectrogram has only spectrogram_freqs frequencies
mel_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(mel_basis.shape[0], bias=False, trainable=False))
nw = mel_layer(nw)
mel_layer.set_weights([np.transpose(mel_basis)])

# Change the time / frequency axis
nw = Permute((2, 1))(nw)
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried and show the error.

Comment: In Keras you need to use appropriate tensors - which take as values `numpy.array`s instead of passing it directly to `backend` functions. You also need to provide a appropriate `lambda` layer.